# Why if I am create big size array I am getting Segmentation fault(core dumped) error?

Tags: arrays, c, linux

So I am working on something and I have a big problem. On my program when I input small array size, I don't have any problem and the program works fine(for example 3x3). When I input the X array with something like 6x6 (i=6, j=6) I get this error and I really don't know why... I am trying to solve it from yesterday and still nothing :( Anybody can help me ? The software that I use in my computer is ubuntu 18.04 if that matters. I will be grateful to anybody is going to help.

My code is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int N,M;  // N=size of rows , M=size of columns
 int **X,**Y;  // array
 int size,i,j,num;
 int freqamount, sizeOfArray;
 float freq;


 printf("\n\nGive me the rows of the table: ");
 scanf("%d",&N);
 printf("\n\nGive me the columns: ");
 scanf("%d",&M);

 size = N*sizeof(int);
 X = malloc(size);

 size = M * sizeof(int);
 for(i=0; i<M;i++){
   X[i] =(int*)malloc(size);
 }
 
 Y = malloc(size);

 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   Y[i] = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
 }

 printf("\n\nGive the number ");
 scanf("%d",&num);

 
 printf("\n\ngive the frequence");
 scanf("%f",&freq);

 sizeOfArray = N*M;
 freqamount =(int) ((freq * sizeOfArray)/100);
 printf("\nIt should appear: %d times\n",freqamount);
/*
     if(freqamount == 100){
       X[i][j] = num;
     }
     if(freqamount == 0){
       x[i][j] != num;
     }
           X[i][j] = rand() % 100;
*/

 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   for(j=0;j<M;j++){
     X[i][j] = num;
   }
 }
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   for(j=0;j<3;j++){
     if(j=0){
       Y[i][j] = rand() % 100;
     } 
     if (j=1){
       Y[i][j] = i;
     }
     if(j=2){
       Y[i][j] = j;
     }
   }
   printf("%d\t",Y[i][j]);
 }




 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
   free(X[i]);
 }
 free(X);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? [ask]

Comment: Tried to make the space unlimited for the program but still nothing. After that I did some google search and I found that many people solve it downloading this sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t but still got nothing

Comment: You shove pointers into an int-sized arrays:(

Comment: That has nothing to do with your problem. Try to reduce the code to the minimum size possible that still has the problem you are talking about. [Step through it with a debugger](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/) to see if you are able to identify a particular section that isn't working correctly, etc.

Comment: `size = N*sizeof(int); X = malloc(size);` is wrong, you're supposed to allocate `N` number of *pointers* to `int`, i.e. `N * sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: `size = M * sizeof(int);` is correct, but the loop after `for(i=0; i<M;i++)` is wrong because you loop over `M` instead of `N` .

Comment: @MarcoBonelli well, if the pointers are 64-bit, the 'size' will be half that required, (assuming 32-bit int).

Comment: While `size = M * sizeof(int)` is correct for the rows inside `X`, it's not correct later when you allocate `Y` as `Y = malloc(size);`. Again you must allocate space for *pointers* to `int`. You also don't initialize all `N` elements of `Y` that is needed later.

Comment: `printf("%d\t",Y[i][j])` is also wrong as the value of `j` will be equal to `3`, which is one out of bounds of `Y[i]`.

Comment: Lastly, you never free the memory you allocate for `Y`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am going to run some test and I will re-reply back mate. Thank you very much for you feedback

Comment: So I did a new small test file. I input my X and Y arrays. I try to free them with this way   for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    free(X[i]);
  }
  free(X); for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    free(Y[i]);
  }
  free(Y);
    The program is running but it gives me this error double free or corruption(out) and Aborted(core dumped). The problem is that I didn't try to free X or Y array second time. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @4386427 I never said that. I was only encouraging OP to do more research and debugging before dumping the code along with two lines of text that basically say "find the bug for me". Creating a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal) is 90% of asking a good question.

Comment: ` if(j=0){` will not do what you want, you need a `==`. A compiler with warning tuned on should have tell you (like `gcc -Wall...`)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the dump with symbols, and look at the PC to see where the dump was triggered, it should be obvious what the problem is.  You will need to think about the code, and what it is doing at the moment it crashed (the line before the Program Counter address).

Comment: this way to  malloc Nx3 array is wrong ? I think this is the problem   Y = malloc(sizeOfArray);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    Y[i] = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
  }

Comment: I am trying to help you understand how to debug code.  When you get a core dump, things have gone very badly.  You have broken the rules of C.  Seeing that, recognizing how to find the line of code that is at fault, will help you in the future.

Comment: I am not going to help you debug your class assignment.  Or whatever.  You have to understand the code you write, that is your job.